# Dynamic HashMap in XSLT

Tags: java, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert XML to JSON using XLST. Basic conversion is working fine. But I am having a Map where value is List. The Map is dynamic so I can not hardcode value in XSLT. I have declared a variable in XSLT with a name and replace content dynamically. After replacing the variable value in XSLT, it looks like

```
<xsl:variable name="myMap" select="{key1:[value1, value2], key2:[value2, value3]}"/>
```

But I do not get any example to process the above map in XSLT. I want to get List based on the map key.

Comment: Is your question specifically about XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, It is specific to 1.0